# What programming language has this syntax?

Tags: programming-languages

I came across this statement as code, on a programming puzzle web site.

> (i. >./) (0 >. +)/@:|.\ a

Wondering, what language has these type of syntax?

Comment: Please provide a link to the page where you saw this

Comment: I lost it, closed accidently, still searching...

Comment: Googling that exact string produced a really weird collection of pages. I think it only considered the 'i' and 'a' in the search, and quoting the string didn't help much. Asking here might have been the only way to find out if you didn't already know the answer.

Comment: SymbolHound found this page, pity they don't crawl the rest of the net:  http://symbolhound.com/?q=%28i.+%3E.%2F%29+%280+%3E.+%2B%29%2F%40%3A%7C.%5C+a

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's probably the J programming language. For example, here's a [page](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/release/idotmaxmin.htm) that mentions the (i. >./) idiom

(I wanted to say Perl as a joke ;)

Comment: That's less of a joke than you might think :-)

Comment: Yes, it is. Now at least we know where Brainf*ck comes from.

Comment: I thought that page was opaque until I wandered around the rest of the site. Not only do they want a language to be as terse as possible, but they seem to apply the same style guide to the documentation. They named the user manual "Usr", for instance.

Answer (score 1):

K has some really weird syntax. Also, on the list are APL, R and some other weird languages, which are pretty powerful for their purposes, and in some cases, use their own character set. 
My guess would be that this is closer to K than anything else.

Comment: R's syntax is weird but nowhere _that_ weird :)

Answer (score 0):

APL had that *sort* of syntax. Not that exact syntax but near the same level of readability. Did the web site not offer a clue?

Forth, as well, had similar syntax `(R> . .@)` but it still tended to have spaces between words, unlike your sample.

**Update:**

Actually, it *does* look like APL or a variant thereof. See this link [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#PboGxoZH13w/AMEND.JS&q=%22(i.%20%3E./)%20%22) for the line:

```
(i. >./) z     NB. Hook. Linear index of pivot
```

The comments at the top of that file:

```
NB.  AMENDMENT:  "A Change for the Better"
NB.  Vector, vol. 9, No. 3 (January 1993) p.134-140. Used J Version 5
NB.  x i} m  Amend was amended in Version 4 and further amended
NB.  in J Release 2
NB.  Executes with J Release 2.05, March 1995
```

so it's the J variant of APL. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J_(programming_language)) if you want to enhance your migraines.

Comment: APL seemed likely but @ isn't in their symbols. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)#APL_symbols_and_keyboard_layout

Comment: Might be J, an APL descendant.

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly valid c++ code. Just give me a couple of #define directives, and this cryptic code will print a "Mary has a little lamb"...

Just kidding, but why not? Preprocessor may translate almost anything into a valid code...